# Apache Commons Net POP3 connecting with Gmail

Tags: java, pop3, apache-commons-net

I am using Apache Commons Net's POP3 support to retrieve emails from my Gmail inbox. I use the following code to open a connecting with Gmail's POP3 server:

```
String server = "pop.gmail.com";
String username = "<my gmail>";
String password = "<my password>";

POP3Client pop3 = new POP3Client();
pop3.setDefaultTimeout(15000);
pop3.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out), true));

System.out.println("Connecting...");
try {
    pop3.connect(server, 995);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
}
```

But this causes the following error:

```
java.io.EOFException: Connection closed without indication.
    at org.apache.commons.net.pop3.POP3.__getReply(POP3.java:117)
    at org.apache.commons.net.pop3.POP3._connectAction_(POP3.java:153)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:189)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:209)
    at com.sms.POP3Mail.main(POP3Mail.java:66)
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the implicit flag in the constuctor to connect to Gmail and use the POP3SClient:

```
POP3SClient pop3 = new POP3SClient(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Google requires SSL when using POP3. I added SSL authentication and it's all good now.

Comment: How exactly did you do SSL?